# Using the read command to parse du -s output in linux shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script to perform actions if a users home directory if over a certain size. Unfortionately when I try to use the read command to split up the `du -s` output I get 'command not found' since it tries to pass the number through to the shell, not into a variable like I want. Here's what I have so far for the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
for i in `ls`
do
    j=`du -s $i`
    #this line gives me the error
    k=`$j |read first;`
done
```

I get output like the following:

```
./takehome.sh: line 6: 3284972: command not found
```

where 3284972 is the size of the directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll want something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *
do
    j=`du -s "$i" | cut -f 1`
    echo $i size is $j
done
```

Reading into another variable, read, and playing with that seems redundant.

I believe a more elegant solution is Jonathan Leffler's second method (copy-pasted here)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
du -s * |
while read size name
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: That's a heavy way to do it - though the cost of the 'cut' is minimal by comparison with the 'du' which does the heavy lifting, so maybe the objection is more imaginary than real.

Comment: Agreed - your Method 2 does seem way more elegant, and doesn't involve the use of extra commands like cut, set, or even using backswitches.

Comment: Thanks...it could also lose the 'cd /home' and use 'du -s /home/* |'...TMTOWTDI, to quote a (moderately) well-known acronym.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least two ways to do this:

#### Method 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
for i in `ls`
do
    set -- `du -s $i`
    size=$1
    name=$2
    ...
done
```

#### Method 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
du -s * |
while read size name
do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It's understandable that's happening as that's what you're telling it to.  Backticks mean: evaluate this string, run it as a command and give me the output.

Also, `read name` means read data in to the variable `name`.

Try:

```
echo $j | read k
```

Or even removing the previous line:

```
du -s $i | read k
```

(**Edit** - Testing this properly, it works fine in `ksh` but not in `bash` for some reason.  I think it might be something to do with subshells.  Use the backticks and `cut` solution below if you're using bash.)

You could keep your backticks and use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) rather than `read`:

```
k=`$du -s $i | cut -f1`
```

In this case it probably doesn't give you much more, but `cut` is more powerful than `read` which might help you sometime in the future.

Comment: When I use the line k=`echo $j |read first` k doesn't get a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to limit the amount of disk space that users can use, you might want to check out the concept of disk quotas.

Starting point: [Quota @ LQWiki](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Quota)